# Sorting ListBox items clears selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox with

> IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

Problem is if I select more than one item and change sorting order I end up with only one item selected.

```
private ICollectionView FileCollectionView;
FileCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FileCollection);
this.FilesLB.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FileCollectionView);

ObservableCollection<FileData> _fileCollection = new ObservableCollection<FileData>();
public ObservableCollection<FileData> FileCollection
  { get { return _fileCollection; } }



private void SortFiles()
{
    using (FileCollectionView.DeferRefresh())
    {       
        FileCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        FileCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(t.SortFiles.SortBy, t.SortFiles.SortDirection));
    }
```

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are clearing the list. Fix it by storing the selection and reselecting it after you refilled the list.

Comment: I am clearing only SortDescription. If I remove that line it still happens.

Comment: Misunderstood that one, but memorizing the items and reselecting them would work